# Python3: UnicodeEncodeError only when run from crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

first post so be kind please, I have searched a lot around but most things I found are relevant to Python 2.

I have a Python3 script that builds a zip file from a file list; it fails with UnicodeEncodeError only when the script is run from crontab, but it works flawlessly when run from interactive console.
I guess there must be something in the environment but I just can't seem to figure out what.

This is the code excerpt:

```
def zipFileList(self, rootfolder, filelist, zip_file, logger):
    count = 0

    logger.info("Generazione file zip {0}: da {1} files".format(zip_file, len(filelist)))
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for curfile in filelist:
        zip.write(os.path.join(rootfolder, curfile), curfile, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        count = count + 1

    zip.close()
    logger.info("Scrittura terminata: {0} files".format(count))
```

And this is the log output for this code fragment:

```
2012-07-31 09:10:03,033: root - ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/zipfile.py", line 365, in _encodeFilenameFlags
  return self.filename.encode('ascii'), self.flag_bits
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 56-57: ordinal not in range(128)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XBE.py", line 45, in main
    pam.executeList(logger)
  File "/home/vte/vtebackup/vte41/scripts/ptActivityManager.py", line 62, in executeList
    self.executeActivity(act, logger)
  File "/home/vte/vtebackup/vte41/scripts/ptActivityManager.py", line 71, in executeActivity
    self.exAct_FileBackup(act, logger)
  File "/home/vte/vtebackup/vte41/scripts/ptActivityManager.py", line 112, in exAct_FileBackup
    ptfs.zipFileList(srcfolder, filelist, arcfilename, logger)
  File "/home/vte/vtebackup/vte41/scripts/ptFileManager.py", line 143, in zipFileList
    zip.write(os.path.join(rootfolder, curfile), curfile, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/zipfile.py", line 1115, in write
    self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/zipfile.py", line 355, in FileHeader
    filename, flag_bits = self._encodeFilenameFlags()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/zipfile.py", line 367, in _encodeFilenameFlags
    return self.filename.encode('utf-8'), self.flag_bits | 0x800
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcc3' in position 56: surrogates not allowed
```

This is the crontab line:

```
10 9 * * * /home/vte/vtebackup/vte41/scripts/runbackup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And this is the content of runbackup.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash -l

cd /home/vte/vtebackup/vte41/scripts

/usr/local/bin/python3.2 XBE.py
```

The file on which the exception happens is always the same, but it doesn't seem to include any non ascii chars:

```
/var/vhosts/vte41/http_docs/vtecrm41/storage/2012/July/week4/169933_Puccini_Gabriele.tif
```

OS is Ubuntu Linux LTS 10.04, Python version 3.2 (installed side by side as altinstall with other Python versions).
All Python source files have this shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2
```

as very first line

Can you help me finding what's wrong and how to fix this problem?

Comment: For an unknown reason when zipfile tries to encode the filename to embed info in it, filename has a [unicode surrogate](http://www.htmlescape.net/dc/unicode_char_dcc3.html). Maybe an OS problem? Can you log `curfile` in your script?

Answer (score 21):

A team member found the resolution in a [Python bug thread](http://bugs.python.org/issue13643#msg149941).

The issue was fixed by prepending a LANG directive to the script command:

```
* * * * * LANG=it_IT.UTF-8 /home/vte/vtebackup/vte41/scripts/runbackup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I hope this is useful for others because I got myself scratching my head for a while on this :)

Comment: Thanks this saved my life.

Comment: On MacOS X `import sys print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` cron job shows `utf-8` but still I got the error TS mentioned and this solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

Check your locale. On the interactive console, run the command `locale`. Here is what I get:

```sh
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Python determines how to interpret filenames based on either the `LC_CTYPE` or `LANG` environment variable, and I strongly suspect that one of these is set to a different encoding in your cron environment.

If that's the case, your filenames will have been decoded to unicode using a different encoding, one that then results in filenames that cannot be encoded to UTF-8 or ASCII.

Simply set the `LC_CTYPE` variable in your cron definition, either on a line on it's own preceding the time entry, or as part of the command to execute:

```sh
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
* * * * * yourscriptcommand.py
```

As always with python Unicode issues, the answer lies in the [Unicode HOWTO, section on filenames](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames).

Answer (score 2):

for chinese

```
export LANG="zh_CN.utf-8"                                                                            
export LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.utf-8"                                                                        
export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8"                                                                      

/export/zhangys/python3.5.2/bin/python3 diff_reporter.py > /home/admin/diff_script/cron_job.log 2>&1
```