# Django managment command executed by cron cause an error

Tags: django, cron, debian

I have the following cronjob:

```
0 0 * * * source /home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/bin/activate && python /home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/project/manage.py 1c-import >> /home/admin/data/logs/1c-import.log 2>&1
```

So, in log file I see following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/project/manage.py", line 28, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/project/helper/management/commands/1c-import.py", line 94, in handle
    print 'Product [%s] with price %s and qty %s' % (product_title, product_price, product_qty)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 34-35: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But when I try to manually run thic command - it's ok. What do you think - what may cause this error?

Comment: Rather than activate the venv try: `0 0 * * * /home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/bin/python /home/admin/data/virtualenvs/myapp/project/manage.py 1c-import`

Comment: get the same error again

Answer (score 4):

The problem would be that locale for the cron is not set properly.

In `/etc/environment` set

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This link will be useful: [locale setting for cron job](http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/02/locale-settings-for-your-cron-job/)

And this question also: [Python3: UnicodeEncodeError only when run from crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735363/python3-unicodeencodeerror-only-when-run-from-crontab)

Comment: and after `service cron restart` I see `[warn] /etc/environment has been deprecated for locale information; use /etc/default/locale for LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 instead ... (warning).`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that when running it from a cron job the system tries to convert you product title, price and quantity to ASCII, while it chooses a different encoding when you run it manually.
One or more of your products will have a character in it's title, price and/or quantity which can't be encoded to ASCII.

Does it help if you print the info like this?:

```
ENCODING = "utf-8"
print 'Product [%s] with price %s and qty %s' % (product_title.encode(ENCODING), 
                      product_price.encode(ENCODING), product_qty.encode(ENCODING))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I run command manually it works good - thats why I think problem not in this.

Comment: If another solution allows you to keep to code as is, I'd go for that. If not, try this, it worked for me.

Comment: amazing! it works fine for me! thanks a lot!:-) but I still don't understand why manual run of command have no error?

Comment: At this point, neither do I. My command worked fine on one machine, but not on another. The output of the locale command are identical on both machines. Neither /etc/environment files contain the LANG variable. If I ever find out I'll let you know. :)